# Prove that there is a subsequence of functions which converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The problem is this

> Let $\phi:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded and continuous, and for $n=1,2,\dots$ let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f_n(0)=1/n$ and $f'_n(t)=\phi(t,f_n(t))$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Show that there exists a subsequence $\{f_n\}$ which converges to some $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $F'(t)=\phi(t,f(t))$

I've boiled this down to needing to show that $\{f_n'\}$ converges uniformly to some $f$. Since $\{f_n(0)\}$ converges pointwise to $0$ then this implies that $f'_n\rightarrow f'$ uniformly and I can show that the conditions hold. But I have no idea how to show that ${f_n'}$ converges uniformly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the $f_n$ are Lipschitz continuous with common Lipschitz constant given by the bound on $\phi$. Furthermore they are pointwise bounded, so the Arzèla-Ascoli Theorem can be applied to get subsequence converging uniformly to some continuous limit function. But then $t \mapsto \phi(t,f_{n_k}(t))$ converges uniformly (using that continuity of $\phi$ holds uniformly in the first variable).